# Debugging is failing and project References missing on newest ASP.NET Core release

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Using the newest ASP.NET Core release (i.e. RTM June 27), I cannot get the project to run normally in Debug.  Also, the project References are blank and the Intellisense isn't working if I do F12/Go To Definition.  The strange part is that it will compile fine and work as it should I go to command line and do 'dotnet run'.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both the Tools and even VS 2015.  I've run as Admin also with no luck.  I've tried both creating a new empty web project and also using the samples at https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples.  Nothing seems to fix it.

My guess is that something isn't registered correctly in VS 2015.  Whatever isn't correct seems to survive the uninstall/reinstall process.

Comment: You probably get every bits wrong. June 27 is RTM of .NET Core and Preview 2 of the SDK. Have you followed every steps on http://dot.net? If possible find a clean machine and restart installing.

Comment: Are you a troll, what does this mean? "You probably get every bits wrong."  Of course I followed the steps.  Why would I go through the trouble of an uninstall and reinstall only to skip a few steps?